# jQuery ui effect for not ui jquery

Tags: jquery, show, slide, effects

I'm not using jquery UI but i would like to make element slide and show at same time, from left to right.

So which is the equivalent function of jquery UI?:

```
$(function(){
$(element).show('slide', {direction: 'right'},1000);
});
```

thanks

Comment: you can use `.animate` too

Comment: @DipeshParmar how to dude? pls

Comment: **Example :** `$(element).animate({left: '300px'}, 1000);`

Comment: thx, but animate doesn't shows pfff

Comment: Will this work if the element is hidden to start with?

Comment: @lee_mcmullen same thing i'm trying to say, animate it's ok but if element is hidden it doesn't works smoothly

Comment: just use the opacity from 0 to 1 in animate function.

Comment: I think @bipen's answer is correct: http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/zq6Rx/3/

Comment: Do not set the element hidden by default.Just set the opacity to 0 and then manage it through animate function to be 1 if this appears to be non problematic anywhere.

Comment: @donotusetabtodigitthisnick i have added answer...please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@DipeshParmar has commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498585/jquery-ui-effect-for-not-ui-jquery#comment21942882_15498585), you can use [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to *slide* an element.

```
$(".box").animate({left: "200px", opacity: 1}, 4000);
```

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Rx/6/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(element).hide().animate({width: 'toggle'});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/zq6Rx/3/)

Comment: then hide() it first and then animate.. :)

Comment: If it's already hidden, do you need the `.hide()` call first? http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Rx/5/

Comment: no.. if its hidden then works fine.. :).. no need to hide.. toggle just checks if the element is hidden or not,if hidden  it shows and if not it hides... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `opacity` css property for `hidden` field as you asked.

```
$("#element").animate( { "opacity": "show", left:"200px"} , 1000 );
```

**OR**

```
$("#element").animate( { "opacity": 1, left:"200px"} , 1000 );
```